# Conditions for when event-handlers can be called by the browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, dom-events

When working with asynchronous XHR-requests in Javascript, I often wonder, if there are
conditions, for when the `onReadyStateChange`-callback can be called by the browser. If there
were none, some problems would be caused, as shown by the following example:

```
var state = -1;
doAsyncXhrReqeust("foo.bar", function() {
   state = 1;
});
function doStateDependendAction() {
   if(state === 1)
      alert("file is available");
   
   // if the callback above was called at this point, nothing would happen
      
   else if(state === -1)
      alert("file isn't available");
}; 

function doAsyncXhrRequest(url, callback) {
   // simple AJAX-helper-function
};
```

As you can see, the `doStateDependendAction` does just nothing, if the state changes between the
two if-statements which check the state.
I know that in this case, I'm able to work around this by assigning the state to a local
variable before checking the value.

So the question is, whether I always need to take care about this.
My question also applies to other events, such as user-interaction and web-workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two tasks running at the same time, so the one task that will execute the JS code `doStateDependendAction` will always execute entirely before the callback can be executed.
Even if you let your `doStateDependendAction` function stall the event-loop for hours, the network task from the ready-state change will still be queued in the task-queue, waiting for this task to end.

So no, no need to take this into consideration, there is no risk that the callback gets executed in the middle of your function (that is, unless your function calls that callback itself, or dispatches the event synchronously).

Comment: Finally after more than 10 years somebody answered it :-D I already learned it a few years ago. Fortunately today there are many good videos about the event loop and task queue. But it seems back then in 2010 nobody was able to answer it